# First motivation for extending Riemann Zeta to complex domain?

Tags: number-theory, euler, primes

Euler developed the Euler Product Formula which shows that the Riemann zeta function encodes information about the prime.

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^{s}}=\prod_{p}(1-\frac{1}{p^{s}})^{-1}$$

Riemann is considered to have been the first to extend the domain $s$ from the real numbers  $\mathbb{R}$ to the complex domain $\mathbb{C}$.

**Question 1**: what motivated the need to widen the domain from the reals to the complex domain?

**Question 2**: what is the history around extending the domain from integers $s\in\mathbb{Z}$ to $s\in\mathbb{R}$?

For clarity, I am not asking about the analytic continuation of the zeta function.

Comment: Whenever you have an ANALYTIC function, it is reasonable to study it in complex domain. (The reason is uniqueness theorem). So there is nothing special about zeta function here.

Comment: For Question 2: Continuous (even analytic) functions on $\mathbb{R}$ are certainly better to study than functions $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$ especially when the range consists not only of integers.

Comment: Riemann’s motivation for viewing the zeta-function as a function of a complex variable was to outline a set of ideas based on complex analysis that he expected would lead to a proof of the prime number theorem (and they eventually did). This is the content of his paper on the zeta-function. Nobody before him had considered the zeta-function’s domain beyond the real numbers.

Comment: Euler only considered the zeta-function at integers, not as a function of a real variable.  (His proof of infinitude of the primes was at argument *at* $s = 1$, not the more rigorous proof presented today using a limit as $s \to 1^+$.) I would not be surprised if the first person to seriously consider the zeta-function as a function of a real variable was Dirichlet as part of his proof of infinitude of primes in arithmetic progressions.  He was using $L$-functions of characters of a real variable bigger than $1$, and this includes the trivial character (essentially the zeta-function).